# Let $P(x)=x^2+bx+c$, where $b$ and $c$ are integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics, quartics

> Let $P(x)=x^2+bx+c$, where $b$ and $c$ are integers. If $P(x)$ is a
>   factor of both $f(x)=x^4+6x^2+25$ and $g(x)=3x^4+4x^2+28x+5$, then
>
> 1. $P(x)=0$ has imaginary roots
> 2. $P(x)=0$ has roots of opposite sign
> 3. $P(1)=4$
> 4. $P(1)=6$

**My Attempt:**

$f(x)=x^4+6x^2+25$ is always positive, i.e. no roots.

This implies that, $P(x)=0$ has no real roots either.

$\therefore$ Option **(1)** is correct.

I have no idea how to calculate Option **(3)** or **(4)**

All I could see was $f(1)=32$, $g(1)=40$, hinting me at **(3)**.

Any hints would be really helpful thanks.

Comment: Why not use the euclidean algorithm to get the gcd of the two polynomials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  It is quite easy to factor $x^4+6x^2+25$ into irreducible factors (over $\mathbb{Z}$):
$$x^4+6x^2+25=(x^2+5)^2-4x^2\,.$$
So, what should you do?

> The two irreducible factors of $x^4+6x^2+25$ are $x^2-2x+5$ and $x^2+2x+5$.  (By the way, they are obviously irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$, whence also over $\mathbb{Z}$, as they are positive polynomials, i.e., without real roots.)  Since the coefficient of $x$ in either of these polynomials is not $0$, (1) and (2) cannot be the answer.  The values at $x=1$ of these polynomials are $4$ and $8$, respectively.  Thus, (3) is the only possible choice.  Indeed, $$3x^4+4x^2+28x+5=(x^2-2x+5)(3x^2+6x+1)\,.$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Will accept in 3 minutes.

Comment: You get two irreducible factors of $f(x)$.  Which of the two divides $g(x)$?  Anyhow, at this stage, without even dividing $g(x)$, you can answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

The quartic $f(x)$ has $4$ roots: $1\pm2i$ and $-1\pm2i$. Of these, only the first $2$ are roots of $g(x)$. Therefore, $P(x)=(x-1-2i)(x-1+2i)=x^2-2x+5$. Now, note that $P(1)=4$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$f(x)= (x^2+3)^2+16 $$ $$= (x^2+3+4i)(x^2+3-4i)$$
$$ = (x^2-(1-2i)^2)(x^2-(1+2i)^2) $$ 
$$= \color{red}{(x-1+2i)}(x+1-2i)\color{red}{(x-1-2i)}(x+1+2i)$$
$$ = \big(\color{red}{(x-1)^2-4i^2}\big)\big((x+1)^2-4i^2)$$
$$ = (x^2-2x+5)(x^2+2x+5)$$

Now it is easy to see $$g(x)= (x^2-2x+5)(3x^2+6x+1)$$

So $P(x)= x^2-2x+5$.

Comment: How did you see that $3+4i=(1-2i)^2$? I haven't really worked on factorization in complex numbers.

Comment: I was trying to find something like $(c+di)^2$. You don't have a lot options for that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

since $P(x)$ is a factor

$f(x)=x^4+6x^2+25=P(x)*q(x)$ and $g(x)=3x^4+4x^2+28x+5=P(x)*q'(x)$

where $q,q'$ quadratic polynomials

$3f(x)-g(x)=14x^2-28x+70=P(x)*(3q(x)-q'(x))$

$P(x)*(3q(x)-q'(x))=14(x^2-2x+5)$

since $P(x)$ is a quadratic $(3q(x)-q'(x))$ must be a constant$(14)$

thus $$P(x)=x^2-2x+5$$

Comment: I really like this answer.